# 4 player children's game in python

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I want to be able to run the following python script for 4 people. Specifically, I want to be able to print  the winner and their number of turns needed to win the game. I am new at python, and scripting in general so please take it easy on me...

1.Take 1 cherry from tree
2.Take 2 cherries from tree
3.Take 3 cherries from tree
4.Take 4 cherries from tree
5.Dog: Take two cherries from your bucket and place them back on your tree. (If you have only one cherry, put that one back. If you have none do nothing.)
6.Bird: Take two cherries from your bucket and place them back on your tree. (If you have only one cherry, put that one back. If you have none do nothing.)
7.Spilled basket: replaces all cherries on tree

```
import random

spinnerChoices = [1, 2, 3, -2, -2, -10]
total_turns = []

for i in range(10000):
    cherriesOnTree = 10
    turns = 0
    while cherriesOnTree > 0:

        spinIndex = random.randrange(0, 6)
        spinResult = spinnerChoices[spinIndex]

        #print "You spun " + str(spinResult) + "."

        cherriesOnTree += spinResult

        if cherriesOnTree > 10:
            cherriesOnTree = 10
        elif cherriesOnTree < 0:
            cherriesOnTree = 0

        #print "You have " + str(cherriesOnTree) + " cherries on your tree."

        turns += 1

    print "It took you " + str(turns) + " turns to win the game."
    total_turns.append(turns)

mean_turns = sum(total_turns)/len(total_turns)
print 'It took you {} turns on average to win the game.'.format(mean_turns)
lastline = raw_input(">")
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a question? You might want to look into python "classes" for Object-Orientated Programming. That would allow you to keep track of the state of each player as the game progresses.

Comment: What problem are you having? Please update the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are helpful sections on [ask].

Comment: Using a list, how do i go about setting up a loop such that the players take turns spinning the spinner?                                                                                          players = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3', 'player4']


for player in players:
    if cherriesOnTree = 10: 'win'(players)
    spinResult()
    #print "winner " + str(players) + "."

Comment: Reading [ask] and [mcve] may be beneficial...